# How to Override parameters for CI/CD pipeline for azure daafactory For Databricks (Workspace Url and Cluster ID)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am doing CI/CD integration for one data factory to another I am Successfully able to Create the release and abe to copy from my Dev to UAT environment I am able to copy my pipelines Triggers and the Link Service
The problem I am facing In just copying Databricks Links Service

As we know we have to override the parameters of our environment, In Databricks Option comes only to override for an Access token.
And Databricks require three parameters workspace URL and ClusterID, As there is no option to override these two. My workspace URL and Cluster ID is in the production environment is copied of MY Dev environment. Although the Token is copied Successfully which results in the Unsuccessful Connection due to workspace URL NA clusterId.

[image]

As you see inside of pic for data bricks three params are required
and Override Template parameter is giving for an only access token

Comment: Accept the answer if it is helpful as it will be beneficial for community members

Answer (score 2):

Those properties can be parameterized from ARM Template by defining parameters for "Domain" and "existingclusterID" properties as below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi HarithaMaddi-MSFT just to be sure if I Understood it properly in my linked service  section, I have to go in code the section of the DatabricksLinked Service and Use the Above JSON Code for the parameter in the Linked service 
By doing that when I will be overriding those parameters I Can see in the Template as option to override?

Comment: These properties cannot be parameterized from data factory. I am suggesting to modify the ARMTemplate.json and arm_template_parameters.json to add new parameters and map them to domain and existingclusterid. these can now be overwritten when called these templates from deployment pipeline.